# How to sort String array by its component? Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
Date,Lat,Lon,Depth,Mag
20000101,34.6920,-116.3550,12.30,1.21
20000101,34.4420,-116.2280,7.32,1.01
20000101,37.4172,-121.7667,5.88,1.14
20000101,-41.1300,174.7600,27.00,1.90
20000101,37.6392,-119.0482,2.40,1.03
20000101,32.1790,-115.0730,6.00,2.44
20000101,59.7753,-152.2192,86.34,1.48
20000101,34.5230,-116.2410,11.63,1.61
20000101,59.5369,-153.1360,100.15,1.62
20000101,44.7357,-110.7932,4.96,2.20
20000101,34.6320,-116.2950,9.00,1.73
```

I need to sort these data by each criterion

I tried `Double.parseDouble(array[0].split(",").[1])`  but takes too much time using Selection Sort

Is there any way to just sort by not using parseDouble?

Comment: Too much time? How much data have you got? I presume it's more than the 12 lines you have above, because sorting 12 lines should take pretty much no time at all no matter which sort algorithm you use.

Comment: Oh, well that's important information. :)

Comment: You should probably write a few different `Comparator`(s); one to sort by each column you need to sort by.

Comment: what is expected result? do you need to sort the each line or the whole ?

Comment: yeah thats what i was asking for; i need an example...

Comment: i need the whole thing sorted by each category

Answer (score 2):

You have strings that you want to sort by a certain substring interpreted as a Double, so no way around parsing them.  But if you parse each line once, and save those results to sort on, that will be faster than calling parseDouble within each comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could create a class that represents the data on each line. Parse the data into instances of that class and then sort on the objects.